# Angular: Changing font-size using css variables is applying but not reflecting in browser for certain fields

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, css-variables

I am using CSS variables for a feature where the user has an option to change the font-size to small, medium or large. So for most of the fields, it's working as expected. But for certain fields, the value is applied but not reflected

```
:host-context(.mediumFont) {
    --fontSize: 11px;
}
:host-context(.largeFont) {
    --fontSize: 12px;
}
:host-context(.smallFont) {
    --fontSize: 10px;
}
```

```
refClassArray: RefClassInterface[] = [
        { class: 'font-small', refClass: 'smallFont' },
        { class: 'font-medium', refClass: 'mediumFont' },
        { class: 'font-large', refClass: 'largeFont' },
    ];
defaultFontSize = 'mediumFont';

changeFontSize(selector: string) {
        this.defaultFontSize = selector;
        let docBody = document.body;
        console.log(document.getElementById(selector));
        docBody.classList.add(selector);
        this.refClassArray.forEach((refClass: RefClassInterface) => {
            if (selector !== refClass.refClass) {
                docBody.classList.remove(refClass.refClass);
                document.querySelector('#' + refClass.refClass).setAttribute('style', 'font-weight: normal;' + 'pointer-events: auto;');
            } else {
                document.querySelector('#' + refClass.refClass).setAttribute('style', 'font-weight:' + 'bold;' + 'pointer-events: none;');
            }
        });
        this.ieStyles.iEfont(selector);
    }
```

Above is the logic I am using.

[image]

[image]

The first pic is from the element which is working fine. When I hover over the `--font-size`, `11px` is reflected. The second one is the one where it's not working as expected and when I hover over the `--font-size` nothing is appearing. And both these elements are inside `<body>`

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce this issue in stackblitz by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by moving

```
:host-context(.mediumFont) {
    --fontSize: 11px;
}
:host-context(.largeFont) {
    --fontSize: 12px;
}
:host-context(.smallFont) {
    --fontSize: 10px;
}
```

from `app.component.scss` to `styles.scss`. Because the pop-ups are not a part of `app.compontnet.html` they render outside it.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be modifying your html code via direct access. This can open leave your application vulnerable to XSS Attacks for instance.

Instead, the Angular Team recomends the use of the [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2).

Taking your code and modifying it to use it, would lead to the following:

```
refClassArray: RefClassInterface[] = [
        { class: 'font-small', refClass: 'smallFont' },
        { class: 'font-medium', refClass: 'mediumFont' },
        { class: 'font-large', refClass: 'largeFont' },
    ];
defaultFontSize = 'mediumFont';

changeFontSize(selector: string, indexOfClassToAdd: number) {
  this.defaultFontSize = selector;
  const el: Element = document.getElementById(selector));
  // Iterate each class in the list to remove it.
  this.refClassArray.forEach((refClass: RefClassInterface) => {
    // Remove the class from the specific element only if its present.            
    if (el.classList.contains(refClass.refClass) {
      this.renderer2.removeClass(el, refClass.refClass);
    };
  });
  this.renderer2.addClass(el, refClassArray[indexOfClassToAdd].refClass);
};
```

This would imply that you are aware of what is the `class` to be applied (and it being present in the `style.scss` or  and the appropriate scss file).

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity, why are you doing it this way rather than simply using a class with the desired text size?

Either way, it looks like your value is not being applied because your selector is not specific enough.

To correct for this, you could make an artificially specific selector with something like this:

`html > body * { // rules }`

Comment: I am doing this way because I have menu, header, screen (where data is displayed and font change is required) and footer. And the requirement is to change the size of the fonts displaying data. table header, section title etc should not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `ngClass`?
Define three classes

```
.font-small{
    fontSize: 10px
}
.font-medium{
    fontSize: 11px
}
.font-large{
    fontSize: 12px
}
```

Bind something to the user select, like `userChoice: SizeEnum` or something

Then, on your data element, use ngClass to bind

```
ngClass = "{
 'font-small': userChoice === sizeEnum.small,
 'font-medium': userChoice === sizeEnum.medium,
 'font-large': userChoice === sizeEnum.large
}"
```